# Aligned xticklabels for stacked and non-stacked ybar plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am drawing stacked and non-stacked ybar plots side by side. I am struggling with getting aligned xticklabels between the two plots.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis=true,
        xtick={0,1}, xticklabels={a, b},
        height=2cm, width=2cm, xmin=-0.5, xmax=1.5,
        xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}% <-- to align the characters a and b with different height
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,2)};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[ybar, shift={(2.8cm, 0)}]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This basic setup fails due to the fact that stacked bar plots don't include xtick labels by default, while the others do:

[image]

I try to fix this by setting `major tick length=-1mm` for the stacked plot and `major tick length=1mm` for the other one:

[image]

This fixes the x tick lengths, but the x tick labels are still not aligned. I also tried to play around with the node parameters passed to the axis' `xticklabel style={at={(...)}, anchor=...}` parameter, but to no avail.

**How can I get aligned tick labels in this case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you instead of

> This basic setup fails due to the fact that stacked bar plots don't include **xtick labels** by default, while the others do

you mean

> This basic setup fails due to the fact that stacked bar plots don't include **xticks** by default, while the others do

But also this is not true as you can see at the top of the x axis where the ticks *can be seen*. To also see them at the (lower) x axis just add `axis on top` because then -- as the option says -- the axis is drawn over the plots and not the other way round. Alternatively you could just not fill the bars. Also then you would see that the ticks *are drawn*. But by default they are drawn **inside** the axis for stacked bar plots (as it is done for the y axis, too).

So the simple solution is to force to draw the `xticks` either inside or outside. In the code below I have chosen to just draw the `xticks` inside.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis/.append style={
            axis on top,            % to show that `xticks` are drawn `inside`
            xtick align=outside,    % force all `xticks` to be drawn `outside`
            scale only axis=true,
            xtick={0,1},
            xticklabels={a, b},
            height=2cm,
            width=2cm,
            xmin=-0.5,
            xmax=1.5,
            % to align the characters a and b with different height
            xticklabel style={
                text height=1.5ex,
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,2)};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[ybar, shift={(2.8cm, 0)}]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thanks for this! the `xtick align=outside` option was really all I needed. I wasn't able to find it, for some reason. cheers